# How can I edit the markdown font colors in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse, markdown, readme

For dark color schemes in eclipse, the default markdown colors are hard to read. This makes it difficult to edit README.md files, for example.

It took me a while to find the right setting to change font color and thought I would share the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. Not sure where the downvote came from

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Eclipse, open:

```
Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > WikiText
```

Select "WikiText", **not** any of the subfolders.

From here, there are inputs where you can change the color style. For example:

```
color: #ccc;
```

You must close and restart Eclipse for the settings to take effect.

There appears to be a bug in WikiText > Appearance, as changes made there did not take effect for me.

Comment: In **Mars**, the WikiText > Appearance changes do affect the output in the "Preview" tab but still require an Eclipse restart before they take effect.

Comment: in Neon (4.6.0), close the markdown file and open it again for the changes to apply. Might work for older versions too.